# Java Regular Expression and Groups Capturing

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which is multi line as shown below:

```
Alert null has been generated for policy ENG_POLICY Object: backtk2a.tk.fw.gs.com 
Component:
Description: Client: ABC
Server: ABCD
Error: ABCDE Connection timed out
Group: Group1
Schedule: test
Job: JobName
Status: failed
Level:
Resolution: Please resolve
```

I need to extract values of

```
ABCD from Server: ABCD,
JobName from JOB: JobName,
ABC from Description: Client:ABC
```

Can someone please explain how i can extract the above three values using regular expression.
I tried this but its not working as it returns rest of the string. Please note that the ordering is not constant in String.

```
Pattern actionPattern = Pattern.compile(".*Description: Client: (.*) Job: (.*) .*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to capture the characters you want.

```
String s = "Alert null has been generated for policy ENG_POLICY Object: backtk2a.tk.fw.gs.com \n" +
"Component:\n" +
"Description: Client: ABC\n" +
"Server: ABCD\n" +
"Error: ABCDE Connection timed out\n" +
"Group: Group1\n" +
"Schedule: test\n" +
"Job: JobName\n" +
"Status: failed\n" +
"Level:\n" +
"Resolution: Please resolve";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?mi)^(?:Server:|Job:|Description: Client:)\\s*(.*)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABC
ABCD
JobName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash. It worked. One more questions, how do you subscribe to the posted question from users.